How do you resolve this "'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint" issue?
I'm trying to make some helpers to deal with optimistic updates that add new items to the cache. (E.g. the user submits a form to create a report with just the name, I add that to the cache, later the report is refetched with the name and whatever other data that comes from the server.)
I'm at:
const maybeLoading = Symbol('maybeLoading')
    
type MaybeLoadingState<T, TProps extends keyof T> = {
  [maybeLoading]: true;
} & Pick<T, TProps>
type MaybeLoading<T, TProps extends keyof T> = MaybeLoadingState<T, TProps> | T
type LoadingStateOf<TMaybe extends MaybeLoading<any, any>> = TMaybe extends MaybeLoadingState<infer T, infer TProps> ? MaybeLoadingState<T, TProps> : never;

function isLoading<T extends MaybeLoading<any, any>>(val: T): val is LoadingStateOf<T> {
  return !!(typeof val === 'object' && val != null && maybeLoading in val && val[maybeLoading]);
}

function isLoaded<T>(val: MaybeLoading<T, any>): val is T {
  return !isLoading(val);
}

but the typings of isLoading aren't quite right. (See it on StackBlitz.)
I get the error:
A type predicate's type must be assignable to its parameter's type.
  Type 'LoadingStateOf<T>' is not assignable to type 'T'.
    'LoadingStateOf<T>' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'unknown'.
      Type 'MaybeLoadingState<unknown, never>' is not assignable to type 'T'.
        'MaybeLoadingState<unknown, never>' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'unknown'.

How do I fix it without dodging the type system using any or as?

• Please [edit] to fix/remove typos, like MaybeLoading<T> without a second type argument, and maybeLoading in val without checking if val is null and returning a non-boolean for the type guard function • Maybe there's some better way to write your types, but a general solution to the error with a type predicate is to intersect the input type, since (x: T) => x is U might not compiler but (x: T) => x is T & U will, as shown in this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer or find a duplicate; if not, what's missing?

@jcalz fixed, and yeah it's close enough, trying to clean it up actually got me to understand what the error means too

@jcalz I ended up tweaking it to this which gets rid of the confusing intersect type when narrowed and just gives me a plain MaybeLoadingState
